# Keep game name after complete rebuild, engine migration and change from 2D to 3D?

Tags: marketing

I have published an Alpha version of a game with XNA in 2D, but I am now learning Unreal with full intention of porting the game to 3D there. I expect that in 3 months time, or less with a little luck, I will have a comparable version of the game in 3D, but I am already really close to the point where I can release some early footage.

With this in mind, I am also beginning to think about the game's promotion, its IndieDB page has it listed as a 2D XNA game, but there's two considerations:

a) Should I change the engine, given that earlier images and uploads are still there and I haven't got a release to replace them with?

b) Should I keep the name, considering that, 1) it is associated with the 2D game, and 2) search results bring up Fallout content, and the abbreviation SW is already fully associated with Star Wars?

I am, in the meantime, going to try to contact IndieDB and see if I am even allowed to change the game's listing (in terms of game engine and type) and will edit the post when I have an answer.

Comment: There are several game franchises that made the transition between 2D and 3D (Zelda and Mario) but they were marketed as *different games*.

Comment: Yes indeed... After all, I believe they actually made the transition with different games rather than in the middle of a game's alpha phase, while I sort of consider this to be the same game..

Comment: If you consider it to be the same game, and you feel the name is still appropriate, then keep it.